# Search subdirectories for Inno Setup DestDir

Tags: windows-installer, installation, inno-setup, acrobat, pascalscript

I am attempting to use Inno Setup to distribute a file used as a plug-in by another application. If it cannot find the plug-in destination, it should still install itself into the Program Files directory, providing the user with manual instructions.

Hats off to [Tlama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) for providing some code that was used in a similar problem: [Inno Setup find subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24784031/850848).

The follow script lays out the basic setup I am hoping to achieve, with comment where the script is incomplete. I'm just in over my head. :-)

1. How to pass the found directory back to `StampTargetDir` (currently just a MsgBox)
2. How to search all subdirectories under the specified directory name (i.e. 'Stamps')
3. How to limit the search of all subdirectories (#2) to just a few named subdirectories living in `{pf}` or `{localappdata}` (i.e. "Adobe" and "Acrobat")
4. Make the file plug-in installation under `[Files]` conditional on finding the 'Stamps' directory.

P.S. I know searching has some obvious disadvantages. However the "Stamps" directory is unlikely to be used in other areas (see #3).

```pascal
[Files]
; Install all the files in a user specified location.
Source: "C:\mydir\readme.pdf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\mydir\stamp.pdf"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; If found, install the stamp file in the Adobe Acrobat or Reader Stamp directory.
Source: "C:\mydir\stamp.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:StampTargetDir}"; Flags: ignoreversion


[Tasks]
Name: pf; Description: "&All users on this computer."; GroupDescription: "Configure Acrobat stamp plug-in:"; Flags: exclusive
Name: local;  Description: "&Only the current user (me)."; GroupDescription: "Configure Acrobat stamp plug-in:"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: none;  Description: "&Do not configure stamps (manual setup)."; GroupDescription: "Configure Acrobat stamp plug-in:"; Flags: exclusive unchecked

[Code]
function GetFirstMatchingSubfolder(const Path: string; out Folder: string): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  FindRec: TFindRec;
begin
  Result := False;
  if FindFirst(ExpandConstant(AddBackslash(Path) + '*'), FindRec) then
  try
    repeat
      // *** THIS DOES NOT SEARCH SUBDIRECTORIES ***
      if (FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY <> 0) and
        (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') and
        (FindRec.Name = 'Stamps') then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Folder := AddBackslash(Path) + FindRec.Name;
      end;
    until
      not FindNext(FindRec);
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

function StampTargetDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('pf') then
    // *** THIS NEEDS TO BE 'Stamps' DIRECTORY FOUND UNDER {pf}
    Result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\pf'
  else if IsTaskSelected('local') then
    // *** THIS NEEDS TO BE 'Stamps' DIRECTORY FOUND UNDER {localappdata}
    // Assuming {localappdata} is the user's Application Data Folder
    // Typically C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data.
    Result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\local'
  else
    Result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\none'
end;

// *** This procedure is just for testing. The results of
// GetFirstMatchingSubfolder should be used by StampTargetDir
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  S: string;
begin
  // *** THIS DOES NOT LIMIT SEARCH TO {pf}\Adobe or {pf}\Acrobat ***    if GetFirstMatchingSubfolder(ExpandConstant('{pf}'), S) then
    MsgBox('An extra copy will go in here: ' + S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you trying to find "Stamps" folder under any "Adobe" folder in Program Files? Doesn't the "Stamps" folder have a fixed location under the "Adobe" folders? Do you really need to search it dynamically?

Comment: I wish! The Acrobat stamp folder is usually under \Program Files\Acrobat\plug-ins\Annotations\Stamps\ but versions 9 and below include the version number in the folder name, like \Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat\[version]\Stamps. Reader also version names, like Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\plug_ins\Annotations\Stamps. If I had no other choice, I'd fix the directory to Acrobat\plug-ins\Annotations\Stamps\, but would still be left the problem of #4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To pass the path from `InitializeWizard` to `StampTargetDir`, use a global variable. Though I suggest you better use `CurStepChanged(ssInstall)` instead of `InitializeWizard`, unless you need the path earlier than during the actual installation.
2. Use recursion in `GetFirstMatchingSubfolder`.
3. The cleanest solution is to run `GetFirstMatchingSubfolder` multiple times with specific roots (i.e. twice, for Adobe and for Acrobat)
4. Use [`Check` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck).

The code can be like:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "C:\mydir\stamp.pdf"; DestDir: "{code:GetStampsFolderPath}"; \
    Check: WasStampsFolderFound; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]

const
  StampsFolderName = 'Stamps';

var
  StampsFolderPath: string;

function WasStampsFolderFound(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (StampsFolderPath <> '');
end;

function GetStampsFolderPath(Params: string): string;
begin
  Result := StampsFolderPath;
end;

function GetFirstMatchingSubfolderRecursively(const Path: string; Name: string; out Folder: string): Boolean;
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  FolderPath: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  Log(Format('Searching in %s', [Path]));

  if FindFirst(AddBackslash(Path) + '*', FindRec) then
  try
    repeat
      if (FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY <> 0) then
      begin
        FolderPath := AddBackslash(Path) + FindRec.Name;
        if CompareText(FindRec.Name, Name) = 0 then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Folder := FolderPath;
          Log(Format('Match: %s', [Folder]));
        end
          else
        if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          Result := GetFirstMatchingSubfolderRecursively(FolderPath, Name, Folder);
        end;
      end;
    until Result or (not FindNext(FindRec));
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  RootPath: string;
begin
  Log(Format('CurStepChanged %d', [CurStep]));

  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    if IsTaskSelected('pf') then
    begin
      // this should be pf32 or pf64 specifically,
      // depending on where Adobe installs the applications
      RootPath := ExpandConstant('{pf}\');
    end
      else
    if IsTaskSelected('local') then
    begin
      RootPath := ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\');
    end;

    if RootPath = '' then
    begin
      Log(Format('No task selected, will not search for %s', [StampsFolderName]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Searching for %s folder under %s', [StampsFolderName, RootPath]));

      if GetFirstMatchingSubfolderRecursively(RootPath + 'Adobe', StampsFolderName, StampsFolderPath) or
         GetFirstMatchingSubfolderRecursively(RootPath + 'Acrobat', StampsFolderName, StampsFolderPath) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Found %s folder at %s', [StampsFolderName, StampsFolderPath]));
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('%s folder not found anywhere', [StampsFolderName]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent, you solved this, and it is a far more reliable approach than I could have hoped for. And, after more than a week of struggling with this, you have no idea how happy I am! Thank you!